# Kie Server Guided Descision table rules not fired from REST API

Tags: rest, drools, drools-guvnor, kie

I have a small project created on drools workbench deployed on a KIE server. Using the rest API I am able to insert facts, with rules appropriately fired. However the rules included in guided decision tables do not fire. Here is an example of a request I would send to the KIE server:

```
<batch-execution lookup="defaultKieSession">
<insert out-identifier="applicant" return-object="true" entry-point="DEFAULT">
    <models.Applicant>
        <timeEmployed>35</timeEmployed>
        <employmentStatus>Contract</employmentStatus>
        <violations>[]</violations>
    </models.Applicant>
</insert>
<fire-all-rules/>
</batch-execution>
```

All rules that this data should trigger are fired, except for those included in the Decision table.

When I run a test scenario with the same data, all rules, including the decision table's rules, are fired correctly:
[image]
The problem seems to be related to the use of the REST API. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Here is the Table in question:
 [image]

Violation simply calls a method that appends an error to the violations array.

Inside kmodule.xml I have.

```
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

**Clarification**
Just to be clear my requests fire rules from Guided DRLs, my issue is only with the rules in guided rules table. For example:

Given the rule: 
[image]

If I send this request:
    
    
        
            1994-04-15 11:03:44-0000
            1970-01-13 16:19:41-0024
            Contract
            35
            []

This is a fragment of the response:

[image]

This data should also match the rule in the gdst however it is not fired.

Comment: could you share how your dtable looks like? And also the content of your kmodule.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

While we can't see the condition operators in the table, my guess is the criteria doesn't meet any of the decision table rows/rules.

Mapping the input data to the decision table, we can see that:

1. Employment Status is Contract, so that matches row 1.  In rows 3-11 it is ignored, so depends on the matching of the remaining columns.
2. Employment Duration is probably timeEmployed, and it does not match equality of any row.  If the column operator is >, it matches rows 2-11.  If it is <, then it matches row 1.
3. Job Category is ignored for rows 1 and 2, and has no apparent matching value in the input so rows 3-11 do not match.

Based on those:

- 3 says only rows 1 and 2 could match
- 1 says only row 1 could match of rows 1 and 2
- 2 is indeterminate based on what we see

My guess is row 1 is close but #2 doesn't match.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the image to show the conditions. I have also posted an image of the executed test scenario. Using the same input row 1's rule is fired. However it does not fire when the fact is inserted through the REST API.

Comment: out-identifier is invalid, correct is outIdentifier.  Does it work after correcting that?

Comment: "out-identifier" seems to be correct when I try "outIdentifier" the object is not returned.

Comment: My apologies, yes of course that is correct... So the data seems correct and should match row 1.  Next thoughts are to resolve any data issues: 1. Is "models.Applicant" the correct package and class name (in the request)?  2. Are there leading or trailing spaces around "Contract" (in the DT)?  3. Are there spaces in "Job Category" DT row 1 or completely empty?

Comment: The data is valid as far as I can tell as guided rules fire without problem, I updated the question to show what I mean. I have tried with the jobCategory parameter both absent and empty.